# Bazel: Reference binaries from packages in custom toolchain definition

Tags: cross-compiling, bazel, toolchain, bazel-cpp

### Background

I'm trying to build a custom toolchain definition that references tool binaries from downloadable `http_archive` package.

It seems that if `tool_path.path` is relative Bazel treats it as relative to where toolchain is defined. Ex: `${execroot}/toolchain`.

`http_archive` package contents on the other hand are found in `${execroot}/external/gcc12`

Tool path must be canonical so you can't specify something like `../external/gcc12/bin/gcc`

I looked at other custom toolchain definitions such as:

- https://github.com/agoessling/bazel_bootlin
- https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-toolchain

All of them use wrapper shell scripts that live under toolchain definition (so can be refernced by relative path) and call real binaries via `external/gcc...` which is relative to the execroot.

While this approach works, it can cause problems with `rules_foreign_cc` (See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8438) and anyway seems hacky.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/10967 "Add optional tool_path_origin to Tools in C++ crosstool" was merged in the May of 2020 which seems to allow relative tool paths to be evaluated relative to workspace root. However I don't quite understand how to trigger this behavior.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8438 references https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/5809 as relevant but it was rejected in the end.

Another relevant discussion can be found at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7746

### Question

Is it possible to reference Bazel toolchain binaries from external package without resorting to wrapper shell scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as far as I understand this has mostly been implemented now. Though the interface is kind of painful to use and requires a lot of boiler-plate. As you've mentioned this was introduced in https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/10967. But there is next to no documentation included on how to use this new feature.

After following the breadcrumbs creating my own toolchains. I've found that there are two entirely separate interfaces for defining your tools. The first you've mentioned is to use the tool_paths attribute. There is still no way around the shell script for now. This approach is rather well documented and I assume it's what you're currently doing.

The second is to use the action_config method combined with the separate [tool](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/09c621e4cf5b968f4c6cdf905ab142d5961f9ddc/tools/cpp/cc_toolchain_config_lib.bzl#L442) constructor.

From the [docstring](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/09c621e4cf5b968f4c6cdf905ab142d5961f9ddc/tools/cpp/cc_toolchain_config_lib.bzl#L442);

```
    Describes a tool associated with a crosstool action config.

    Args:
        path: Location of the tool; Can be absolute path (in case of non hermetic
            toolchain), or path relative to the cc_toolchain's package. If this
            parameter is set, tool must not be set.
        tool: The built-artifact that should be used as this tool. If this is
            set, path must not be set.
```

So this looks something like this;

```py
action_config (
    config_name = ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_executable,
    action_name = ACTION_NAMES.cpp_link_executable,
    tools = [
        # NEW label type tool field introduced in #10967
        tool(tool = ctx.executable.my_ld),
    ],
)
```

To get this working in your toolchain you need to go through and create an action_config for each of the ACTION_NAMES. Then you pass your list of action_configs to your toolchain_config.

It's worth noting that while there is some extra-boilerplate here there is also extra flexibility in defining which tools get used and when. There are well defined examples of that [in the bazel docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html#example-usage).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I assume that if action_configs are passed to create_cc_toolchain_config_info, it is no longer needed to pass tool_paths?

Comment: yeah that's right, you pass a list of them as described in the docs https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/cc_common.html#create_cc_toolchain_config_info

Comment: And as far as I remember you don't need to specify the tool_paths anymore. But in any case I defined them in both but just set the tool_path's to `/bin/false` which was the easiest way to ensure that they where being overridden by the action_configs

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly as you've described. `/bin/false` for all tool paths and it is overridden by `action_config`. At least this is the case for Bazel 5.3.0